# Looping a do/while

Tags: java, while-loop

I am new to java programming, and I have only been doing it for a few days, so I'm a little stuck.

What I would like to do is loop back to the "deposit" `do-while` if there is no money in the deposit, or, if there is money in the deposit, loop back to the "bet" `do-while`.

I have no idea how to do this, so I appreciate any help.

Please see the below code:

```
package LectureLoops;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidatingInput {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int bank = 10000;
        int bet;
        int max = 9000;
        int deposit;
        cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();


        do {
            System.out.print("Please make a deposit: ");
            deposit = sc.nextInt();
            if ((deposit > bank))
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds, please enter a valid amount");
        }// end of do
        while (deposit > bank);
        System.out.println("You have successfully made a deposit of " + cf.format(deposit));
        bank = bank - deposit;
        System.out.println("Your new bank balance is " + cf.format(bank));

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your bet: ");
            bet = sc.nextInt();
            if ((bet > deposit))
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds please enter a valid amount or add more funds" + "\nYour current allowance is: " + cf.format(deposit));
            if ((bet > max) || (bet <= 0))
                System.out.println("Maximum bet is " + cf.format(max) + " you entered " + cf.format(bet) + "\nPlease enter a valid amount");
        }// end of do
        while ((bet <= 0) || (bet > max || bet > deposit));
        System.out.print("Thank you for your bet of " + cf.format(bet) + " Your money is good here!\n");
        deposit = deposit - bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + cf.format(deposit) + " left to spend");
    }// psvm end

}// validatinginput end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest putting your main code body in a `while(bank>0)` loop and create separate methods to handle deposit and bet. Then you would have something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bank = 10000;
    int bet;
    int max = 9000;
    int deposit; cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    while(bank>0){
        if(deposit>0){
            bet();
        }
        else {
            deposit();
        }
    }
}

public void deposit(){
    //put deposit code here
}

public void bet(){
    //put bet code here
}
```

Comment: Thats great thank you for your help, I never though about doing it that way. Great Help

Comment: Glad to be of help :) it's always good to use methods for code that will execute multiple times or if it's a large chunk of code. It makes things much easier to read or reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your bet `do-while` loop in another `do-while` which checks if your deposit is exhausted or not and then put the whole logic in infinite `while` loop.

You might want to think of a condition to break this infinite while loop later or else your app will keep on going forever.

Here is a quick code snippet:

```
while(true) { /* Put whole logic inside this loop */

        /* Think of a condition to break this loop */

        do {
            System.out.print("Please make a deposit: ");
            deposit = sc.nextInt();
            if ((deposit > bank))
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds, please enter a valid amount");
        }// end of do
        while (deposit > bank);
        System.out.println("You have successfully made a deposit of " + cf.format(deposit));
        bank = bank - deposit;
        System.out.println("Your new bank balance is " + cf.format(bank));

    do { /* Add a do-while to check if deposit is exhausted or not */
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your bet: ");
            bet = sc.nextInt();
            if ((bet > deposit))
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds please enter a valid amount or add more funds" + "\nYour current allowance is: " + cf.format(deposit));
            if ((bet > max) || (bet <= 0))
                System.out.println("Maximum bet is " + cf.format(max) + " you entered " + cf.format(bet) + "\nPlease enter a valid amount");
        }// end of do
        while ((bet <= 0) || (bet > max || bet > deposit));
        System.out.print("Thank you for your bet of " + cf.format(bet) + " Your money is good here!\n");
        deposit = deposit - bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + cf.format(deposit) + " left to spend");
    } while(deposit > 0);

}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you for your help, its so simple now that i can see how it should be done, I have created a break with the below. 

} while (deposit > 0);
            if ((bank == 0) && (deposit == 0)) {
                break;